# Problem with reverse words function in Python

Tags: python

My code almost works perfectly, with the exception that the first word reversed always 'miss' the last character, the rest of the sentence works fine.
Can anyone find the error to debug this code logic?

```
def reverseWords(str):

    str_len = len(str)
    str = str[str_len-1::-1]

    str_end = ''
    stop = 0
    index = 0

    for i in range(str_len):

        if (str[i] == ' '):
            index = i - 1
            str_end += str[index:stop:-1] + ' '
            stop = i

        elif (i == str_len-1):
            index = i
            str_end += str[index:stop - 1:-1]

    return str_end

print(reverseWords("The greatest victory is that which requires no battle"))
output: battl no requires which that is victory greatest The
```

Comment: Sounds like an off-by-one error somewhere.

Comment: reversing wordwise?  `''.join(w[::-1] for w in wordstring.split())`

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The posted code doesn't do anything, as it's never called.  You haven't produced any attempt to trace the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the test and the ouput. The first word always misses the last character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not reverse slice the string past its beginning, it's not possible.

Example:

```
>>>"baby"[3:0:-1]

'yba'

>>>"baby"[3:-1:-1]

''
```

Comment: That's not the case... your index of start is 3 when it should be 4...

Comment: That's actually the exact case, if you tried it in the terminal you would notice.

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic way to do something like this in Python is to split, reverse and join:

```
def reverse_words(text):
   words = text.split(' ')
   reversed_words = []
   for word in words:
       reversed_words.append(word[::-1])
   reversed_text = ' '.join(text)
   return reversed_text
```

or, in a single expression,

```
def reverse_words(text):
    return ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in text.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

`reverse = lambda sentence: ' '.join(sentence.split()[::-1])`

Comment: This is the most compact I could make it. Do comment back if it works for you.

Comment: I'm looking to debug the code logic above and indentify where is the problem